# How to parse ISO Java date format for mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

Here is a sample document

```
 {  "userId" : "ABC,

        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-09-03T22:07:01.261Z"),
        "body" : {
                "id" : "0082171",
                "name" : "XYZ",
                "palce":"Ind"
        },
        } 



  DBObject match = new BasicDBObject(); 

 match.put("body.id","0082171"); 

   match.put("body.name", new BasicDBObject("$exists",1));
```

I get count of 50999

When I add date field for matching criteria as below I am getting no value.

> > DBObject match = new BasicDBObject(); 
> >     match.put("data.type","score.type");   match.put("body.name", new BasicDBObject("$exists",1)); 
> >     match.put("timestamp","2014-09-03T22:07:01.261Z");

I want my java code to find value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a standard `java.util.Date` object in your query - the Java driver will handle conversion for you.

The problem with your code is that you try to match a String to a ISODate object and that is never going to match.

Here is how your code could look:

```
Date timeStamp = new Calendar().set(2014,09,03,22,07,01).getTime();
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
match.put("data.type","score.type");
match.put("body.name", new BasicDBObject("$exists",1));
match.put("timestamp",timeStamp);
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Can you please give some more idea about this..How can I use java.util.Data